# How to post to a facebook wall from silverlight application

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the facebook c#-sdk v5.0.50.0.  Users of my silverlight application want an option to post information generated by my software onto their facebook wall.

I think the SilverlightInBrowser sample in the SDK is the closest example of what I need in that it prompts the user for permission and also reads user information. I have got that part functioning OK (but do link to any fully working example you know of).

The sample app uses

```
private string[] requestedFbPermissions = new[] { "user_about_me" };
```

I presume I will have to change that to enable posting to the wall, to one of the permissions listed here - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ probably "publish_stream" would be my guess, which I can't test until I get the posting bit working.

The next step is to write the post.  I have not seen a silverlight version of this, so I have adapted slightly an answer to a non-silverlight question, as silverlight is slightly different (e.g. async callbacks).  My code looks like so:

```
    private void fbpost_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new FacebookClient(fb.AccessToken);

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = "test posting - ignore";
        parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/link";
        parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/picture.jpg";
        parameters.name = "Test Post";
        parameters.caption = "Test Post Caption";
        parameters.description = "description here";
        parameters.actions = new
        {
            name = "View on www.example.com",
            link = "http://www.example.com",
        };
        parameters.privacy = new
        {
            value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
        };
        parameters.targeting = new
        {
            countries = "US",
            regions = "6,53",
            locales = "6",
        };
        client.PostCompleted += new EventHandler<FacebookApiEventArgs>(client_PostCompleted);
        client.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters);
    }

    void client_PostCompleted(object sender, FacebookApiEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic result = e.GetResultData();
    }
```

However what happens is I get an error calling `client.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters);`

Attempt by security transparent method 'SimpleJson.Reflection.CacheResolver.CreateDynamicMethod(System.String, System.Type, System.Type[], System.Type)' to access security critical method 'System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(System.String, System.Type, System.Type[], System.Type, Boolean)' failed.

Comment: Thanks.  I believe I have the latest source (from the latest .zip) on the SDK website.  I made that edit (tried 4 times) incremented the version number from 5.0.50.0 to 5.0.53.0 to ensure I got the new dll, and now I get a different error on line 1597 of SimpleJson.cs, the line is `return delegate(object instance) { return getMethodInfo.Invoke(instance, Type.EmptyTypes); };` and the error is `Attempt by method 'SimpleJson.Reflection.CacheResolver+<>c__DisplayClassa.<CreateGetHandler>b__9(System.Object)' to access method '<>f__AnonymousType0`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>.get_name()' failed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug that will be fixed in the future version. (it has already been fixed in my internal code).

for now you will need to grab the latest source code, open silverlight solution Facebook-SL4.sln and remove the symbol called SIMPLE_JSON_REFLECTIONEMIT. Then compile it and use that dll instead.

This was caused due to "security critical method" constructor that we are calling internally.

Comment: Thanks to Prabir, I can confirm this and a subsequent issue encountered have now been resolved and prabir has patched the SDK so I am able to successfully post to a wall from SL.  At the time of writing you'll need to get and build the latest SDK source code changeset yourself not the 'stable' version on codeplex, and then it should work sweet.